# How to remove White Transparent Color from top and bottom of UiPickerView row in IOS

Tags: ios, colors, uipickerview

I have 3 uipickerviews. I want to remove the white transparent color from top and bottom of each pickers row so that it should be clear and all numbers should show as full color.

I also changed the height from this delegate method

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

and also changed the labels height and font size in

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

but didnt resolve my problem.

Please help me in this regard.

you can get the image of screen from below link

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't remove the shadow from a `UIPickerView`.
You have to either create your own view or use a custom one like [`AFPickerView`](https://github.com/arkichek/AFPickerView) (it's on MIT license)